# arcpy open up a script tool window once user save edits

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, editing, python-script-tool

On our map, after user draw a polyline on map and click "Save Edits", we need user to input the attributes related to the polyline drawn. In case user forget or skip this step (input attribute related), I intent to develop a function to open the "Create New Object" window (shows below) automatically, which means once user click "Save Edits" the "Create New Object" window will be open.

The "Create New Object" window is script tool in toolbox.

It should be auto triggered in the ArcGIS editor, my question is must I write my own editor, or is there a way to use the existing editor provided by ArcGIS?

I am using ArcGIS 10.2.

[image]

Comment: I think we still need more details about your workflow.  For example, are you just wanting to capture the attributes of the last feature captured or something else?  If this meant to be part of a Python AddIn or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just substitute existing Save Edits button in the Editor toolbar > Editor using Customize menu > Customize mode in ArcGIS.

Read my answer on [Customizing right click (context) menu of selected feature using ArcPy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/98413)

[About configuring the user interface](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/About_configuring_the_user_interface/00v000000014000000/) (Esri Help)

Comment: Thanks a lot Alex, It seems PolyGeo is correct, I mislead you, sorry about it, I have edit the question, thanks.

Comment: My answer is still applicable. You have a custom script tool which you can add as a button "Save Edits" to the Editor toolbar. This will open the GP dialog box of your tool.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, you can accomplish this without a custom tool.  After you start an editing session, on the Editor Toolbar go to Editor>Options.

On the Attributes tab, check Display the attributes dialog before storing new features, and then select the feature class you want to enforce this behavior on.

Whenever a new feature is created in this feature class, the attribute editor dialog box will open.

[image]

Comment: Yes Zachary, your understanding is right and I have tested on my map, thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi Zachary, I suddenly realise that I haven't find how to config those compulsory fields (those not allow null). It seems even if I leave everything null it still works.